# Mongoose: Delete Item - First One always gets deleted

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am completely new to the fields of Mongoose and MongoDB.
I am currently trying trying to remove one element from my database.

This is my code so far:

My issueModel:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');  // loading module for mongoose
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/issuedb');

var issueSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String,
    priority: String,
    status: String
});

// Constructor Function:
var issueModel = mongoose.model('issues', issueSchema); // have to give the 
name of the collection where the element should be stored + Schema

// Export this Construction Function for this Module:
module.exports = issueModel;  // careful: module != model !
```

My post method for using the delete method:

```
// creating the router for deleting one item:

router.post('/delete/:id', (req, res) => {

console.log(req.params.id);
issueModel.remove({id: req.params.ObjectId})
.setOptions({ single: true }).exec(function (err, deleted) {})
.then(issues => res.render('issue', {issues: issues}));
```

The thing i would like to do here is using the object id - which is correctly stored in req.params.ObjectID according to my console.log, and deleting the corresponding object.

But currently , when i have got a table with about 3-4 entries, always the first one gets deleted. Why is that? I am really TOTALLY new and really tried searching a lot, but i could not find any solution until now. I am happy about any tips that would help me.

What am i doing wrong?
The ID in the URL and the Object.ID are the same! Why is the first object deleted then, not the second or the third? 
I am hopeless right now.

I also read about the remove() option not being really used in todays time. But we were told at university to use this method right now.
I also tried findOneByID and delete methods i found in the mongoose database.

If you need any more code please let me know!

Comment: Using `remove` here is fine, but why are you calling `.setOptions({ single: true })` on the returned Query object?

Comment: In the mongoose database there was the following statement:
"Removes all documents that match conditions from the collection. To remove just the first document that matches conditions, set the single option to true."
When i used remove only it removed the whole issueModel :/

Comment: Shouldn't matter when removing by id. However, given you say that using `findByIdAndRemove` worked, I think you just need to reference `_id` instead of `id`.  As in: `.remove({_id: req.params.id})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one of the convenience methods for this: `findByIdAndRemove`:

```
issueModel.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.ObjectId, function(err) {
  if (err) { ... failed }
});
```

This will remove a whole document matching the ID which I think its what you want, if you want to a remove property from a document that's a different query.

If you don't use one of the convenience methods which just take IDs (have `ById` in them), then you have to convert your ID from a string to an ObjectId:

```
const { ObjectId } = require('mongodb');

issueModel.remove({ id: ObjectId(req.params.ObjectId) }).setOptions({ single: true })
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! With this method it works perfectly fine. But we got this link from our professor: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.remove - so was it somehow his mistake or did i missunderstand?

Comment: @Calimera I think got something wrong - you should be able to use remove but since it isn't a convenience method that only takes IDs you need to convert your ID to an ObjectId - see edited answer